Excel VBA: Need this macro to return the user to the workbook they were in when running the macro
I have a macro for comparing ranges to find matching data. These ranges can be in the same worksheet, different worksheets, or even different workbooks.
This macro is available in the Excel ribbon via users' Personal.xlsb file.
Sometimes, when the macro finishes, the user finds themselves in the 'other' workbook as opposed to the workbook they were in when running the macro. This is not the expected behaviour, so users can get a little disoriented by this.
What change do I need to make in my visual basic code to ensure the macro returns the user to whatever workbook they were in when they first ran the macro?
Here is the code:
    Sub FindMatchingDataV2()
    'This macro was designed to allow users an easy way to find
    'matching data between two ranges, either within the same worksheet or across
    'worksheets within the same workbook, or even between two separate workbooks.
    
    Dim wbActive As Workbook
    Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook
    
On Error GoTo Error_handler:


    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
    
    Dim MySearchRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim findC As Variant
    

        
    Set myrange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Select the range of cells containing the data you are looking for:", Type:=8)
    
    Dim myRangeArray As Variant
    myRangeArray = myrange.Value
    
    Set MySearchRange = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Select the range you wish to investigate:", Type:=8)
    
    Dim MSRArray As Variant
    MSRArray = MySearchRange.Value
    
    Dim Response As String
    Response = InputBox(Prompt:="Specify the comment you wish to appear to indicate the data was found:")
    
    myoutputcolumn = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Enter the alphabetical column letter(s) to specify the column you want the message to appear in.")
        
    Dim outArray As Variant
    ReDim outArray(1 To UBound(myRangeArray, 1), 1 To 1)
        
    Set sht = myrange.Parent
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(myRangeArray, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(MSRArray, 1)
            If myRangeArray(i, 1) = MSRArray(j, 1) Then
                outArray(i, 1) = Response
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    

    
    sht.Cells(myrange.Row, myoutputcolumn).Resize(UBound(outArray, 1), 1).Value = outArray
            

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    wbActive.Activate
    
    MsgBox "Investigation completed."


Exit Sub
 
Error_handler:
wbActive.Activate
MsgBox "This macro will now close."


End Sub


Comment the lines sht.Activate and sht.Range("A1").Select

I think they will always finish in the sheet where they selected myrange. I am afraid that ones complaining about something else selected the respective range in a different workbook than they thought they did... Did the code also return in the correct sheet in such cases? I am afraid, not. Do any of them still use Excel 2003 version?

@Siddharth Rout it looks that MySearchRange may be in another workbook and he needs returning in the initial sheet, the one where myrange has been set...

To be more than sure that users do what they said they did, try firstly activating the workbook, then the sheet, followed by the range. I mean sht.Parent.Activate sht.Activate sht.Range("A1").Select. Even if, it must work as you try in your code, too.

@SiddharthRout Good pickup. I've removed those lines as they were superfluous!

@FaneDuru That's what I thought. But I've tested this myself and indeed the user is correct - when they use the macro on these workbooks the macro does in fact end up with the workbook containing the MySearchRange . So yes, you're correct that MySearchRange is in another workbook in this case.

Try Set wbActive = ThisWorkbook

Store the initially active workbook, and then activate at the end. Add to the start:
Dim wbActive As Workbook
Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wsActive as Worksheet
Set wsActive = ActiveSheet

And at the end:
wbActive.Activate
wsActive.Select


Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the issue, although I'm not sure why since this looks to me like it should work.

You'll need to place the Activate statement before Exit Sub (as well as in the error handler if required). If it's still not working, show us your updated code to see where you've placed it.

I've actually tried placing both aspects of the code in various locations and it makes no difference. I'll edit the question to include the updated code now.

Is it ending on a different workbook, or on a different sheet of the original workbook? The previous answer will take you to the original workbook, but not the original sheet of the original workbook. I've updated the answer to take you to the original sheet of the original workbook.

Sorry Michael, but it's still not working. :( The previous answer didn't return the user to the original workbook at all, let alone the same sheet. The updated answer doesn't result in anything different to the first answer, or indeed to the original code. I'm at a loss, hence why I'm seeking solutions here. I appreciate your input! :)

Sounds like there's some other issue you need to identify, like perhaps the active workbook isn't what you think it is. You need to debug and explain further what's actually happening. Place this bit of code before and after the statement that sets the wbActive object variable, and before and after the statement that Activates the wbActive object:  msgbox ActiveWorkbook.Name

Ok, I created a couple of test workbooks and ran the macro. The result is the same, even though I had no other workbooks open. I added in the msgbox ActiveWorkbook.Name code as suggested by you and interestingly, the four times the message box appears, it lists my 2nd test workbook (even before and after the wbActive object is activated), but what I was seeing on the screen after the wbActive object is activated was the first test workbook. Looking at the screen more closely though, I realised that while the first test workbook is what was visible, it wasn't actually 'active'.
